# While pycharm occured "python 3.5 dose not support variable annotations" while my python version is 3.7.6?

Tags: annotations, pycharm

I have  never installed  python 3.5.The OS is windows,and I choose the right interpreter(python 3.7.6) in settings.
However ,the program can execute successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the code compatibility inspection settings: `File - Settings - Editor - Inspections - Python - Code Compatibility inspection`